# Type inference and unapply

Tags: scala

'sI am using `implicits` to wrap an existing library I need to use, and I'm trying to use `unapply` to achieve a nice syntax.

`Point` is a legacy Java class, and I created this implicit wrapper with an `unapply` method:

```
 implicit class WrappedPoint(point: Point) {
   def unapply(point: Point): (Double, Double) = 
    (point.getX.asInstanceOf[Double], point.getY.asInstanceOf[Double])
   }
```

The reason for the `unapply` is that I want to be able to write this:

```
curve.getPoints.fold(0.0) {
  case (maxRecall: Double, (precision: Double, recall: Double)) =>
    if (recall > maxRecall && precision >= precisionFloor)
      recall
    else
      maxRecall
}
```

Ideally, without even the `Double` mentions: if Scala's type inference could "go through" the `implicit` and the `unapply`, it could guess that `precision` and `recall` can only be of type `Double`.

The current problem I have though, is that the return type of the `fold` is `Any`. This is a bit disappointing, and I would like to avoid having to write an explicit `.asInstanceOf[Double]`. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create Point object companion, and implement `unapply` there.

Also, your unapply signature is wrong, you need to return Option of the touple, not just the touple:

```
object Point(point: Point) {
    def unapply(point: Point): Option[(Double, Double)] = 
     Some((point.getX.asInstanceOf[Double], point.getY.asInstanceOf[Double]))
}
```

Also, I always recommend using `foldLeft` instead of `fold`. `fold` is a particular case of `foldLeft` where the seed type is the same as list's elements type. In this case fold is ok, since both seed and elements are Double, but I personally prefer always using foldLeft (or foldRight if needed.). I belive that changing to foldLeft may fix your type inference problem in this case.

```
curve.getPoints.foldLeft(0.0) {
  case (maxRecall, Point(precision, recall)) =>
    if (recall > maxRecall && precision >= precisionFloor)
      recall
    else
      maxRecall
 }
```

Comment: I would like to avoid having to specify `Point` for unapply-ing the parameters. I would like to avoid having to specify `Double` on the `case` line too, actually.

Comment: You don't need `: Double` but you cannot aboid `Point`. You would only avoid it if your point *was* a tuple but obviously it is a point, not a tuple. You need to put a name of an object with `unapply` method.

Comment: As @Łukasz said, Double types can be infereed, but you can't avoid the explicit unapply. I've edited my original answer without the explicit Doubles.